# How to save a .xlsx with macros that is not corrupted?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsx

I'm on **Ubuntu 20.4 LTS** with **Python 3.10.6** and **Openpyxl 3.0.10**. I'm opening a .xslx file that has macros, I'm able to read it and make the changes I want on the file, but after I save it the file don't open in Windows 10 with Microsoft Office Profesional Plus 2019 but it opens in Libre Office 6.4.7.2, and if I save it as a .xlsx file in Libre Office, then, I'm able to open this "new" file on Excel. The code I'm using is this one:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions import ColumnDimension, DimensionHolder
from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string, get_column_letter
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment, Border, Font, NamedStyle, PatternFill, Side
wb2 = load_workbook("my_file.xlsx", read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
# ... Delete datasheets, create new ones, copy data from a pandas dataframe,
# ... and give format to the cells.
wb2.save("my_new_file.xlsx")
```

Hope someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps a dumb question, but how does your .xlsx file contain macros (should be an .xlsm, right)?

Comment: If you save a file as xlsx it won't keep any macro coded. If you want to save the macros, the file **must** be xlsm.

Comment: I didn't search for it, but I believe a prompt on Libre Office suggest the file has them

Comment: But I believe you are right, the file should not contain macros because it is not a xlsm file

Comment: Searching more I couldn't find macros in the xlsm file. But, I know you can add macro to a .xls file (though this is not the type of file I'm dealing with, this is just a sidenote)

Comment: `.XLS` is not `XLSX`

Comment: Excel insists that workbooks with macros be named `.xlsm`. That aside, XLSM files can be very complicated with form controls and ActiveX components, etc.

Comment: Oh, yes I know .xls is not an .xlsx file, I was just pointing out that those files can contain macros